# Do I need to install SSL on backend if I proxy all of the connection from front-end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following scenario:

1. I use some domain provider to host static files (lets say my site it www.example.com). On the front end, I use SSL that I bought when I was buying the domain.
2. As backend, I port all the requests which have some keyword in the url to my backend (Elastic Beanstalk AWS).

Now, my question is:

Do I need to add any key to my backend, or I should be fine just with what I have (SSL on front end, nothing on backend)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to sniff the traffic with wireshark?

Comment: The traffic will be unencrypted after the entry on the way to the backend, thus if the frontend is compromised, man in the middle is possible. Are there any logins etc. If so I would recommend it!

Comment: How is man in the middle possible? When I send data from browser, it goes first to my domain (with SSL), and then, because in httaccess I've specified the proxy, it goes to the backend.

Comment: ssl is secure up to the front end webserver, after that data will be again in the clear. If Beanstalk is on a different server, and the network between your frontend and the Beanstalk is a public network, then the data is in the clear again. If it is a private network, or if beanstalk is on the same server you are good!

Comment: How do you port request to AWS? Via ssh?

Comment: No, as of today, I port to http://..... [L,P]. You are right, Beanstalk is in the open network... So, does that mean that I should install domains SSL on the Beanstalk?

Comment: Your setup:
`https -> www.example.com -> http -> beanstalk.amazon.something`

You want:
`https -> www.example.com -> https -> beanstalk.amazon.something`

The communication between your frontend and your backend should be handled by amazon!

https should be available on AWS I believe, maybe you just need to redirect from http to https!

Comment: @mahatmanich, alright. Does that mean that I do not need to install any additional SSL's?

Comment: Your ssl setup won't work on the aws side since the certs are not valid for the url on aws!

Comment: Check aws beanstalk for security settings and the entrypoints that they offer! YOU DON'T NEED TO SETUP SSL there, I guess, since amazon should provide that out of the box!

Comment: Just try to change http to https on your requests towards beanstalk!

Comment: alright, will do that and I will let you know whats the outcome :)

Comment: See my answer update, you need to install a self signed cert to get https says amazon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your requests towards amazon are in http then, a man in the middle attack is possible.

You need to use https from amazon aws towards beanstalk, then the entire traffic should be encrypted.

SSL for beanstalk should be provided by Amazon.

Your setup (insecure):

```
https (your ssl cert) -> www.example.com -> http -> beanstalk
```

You want (secure):

```
https (your ssl cert) -> www.example.com -> https (ssl cert amazon) -> beanstalk
```

**Update:**
I guess you need to install a cert there, says amazon!

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

Comment: Thats great answer. Here is a follow up :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771820/load-balancer-and-self-signed-ssl-not-working-on-aws

Comment: Which certificate should I use, if I use the elastic beanstalk only for End-to-End communication? I've tried self-signed, but there was issues.